# Unit test .net 6 console app using IHostApplicationLifeTime

Tags: c#, unit-testing, console-application, moq

I have a class (`CronClass`) that inherits from `IHostedService` with 2 methods which are `StartAsync(CancellationToken)` and `StopAsync(CancellationToken)`.

How do you go about unit testing the `StartAsync` method to verify that the code was executed, using Moq Library?
For example:

```
public class CronClass: IHostedService
{
    private readonly IHostedApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime;
    private readonly IService service;
    // IHostedApplicationLifetime/IService are injected DI to via the constructor
    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        applicationLifeTime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() =>
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                log.LogInformation("Cron Started");
                await service.Process();
            });
        });
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Could you provide working example of CronClass? IHostedApplicationLifetime doesn't exist. applicationLifetime vs. applicationLifeTime

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with creating a mock of `IHostApplicationLifetime`

```
public class MockHostApplicationLifetime : IHostApplicationLifetime, IDisposable
{
    internal readonly CancellationTokenSource _ctsStart = new CancellationTokenSource();
    internal readonly CancellationTokenSource _ctsStopped = new CancellationTokenSource();
    internal readonly CancellationTokenSource _ctsStopping = new CancellationTokenSource();
    public MockHostApplicationLifetime()
    {
    }
    public void Started()
    {
        _ctsStart.Cancel();
    }
    CancellationToken IHostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted => _ctsStart.Token;
    CancellationToken IHostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping => _ctsStopping.Token;
    CancellationToken IHostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopped => _ctsStopped.Token;
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _ctsStopped.Cancel();
        _ctsStart.Dispose();
        _ctsStopped.Dispose();
        _ctsStopping.Dispose();
    }
    public void StopApplication()
    {
        _ctsStopping.Cancel();
    }
}
```

In your unit test create a mock of `IService`. Create instance of `CronClass` and call `cronClass.StartAsync`. Then start `MockHostApplicationLifetime`. It will trigger registered callback `ApplicationStarted.Register`. Then verify that `Process()` was called.

You are starting the task in `Register` method, so it can happen that the unit test can finish before the task is created and `service.Process` is called. In that case I would wait some time before verification.

```
[Test]
public async Task Test1()
{
    var hal = new MockHostApplicationLifetime();
    var mockService = new Mock<IService>();
    var cronClass = new CronClass(hal, mockService.Object);
    await cronClass.StartAsync(CancellationToken.None);
    hal.Started();
    // maybe not needed, test passed without the delay
    //await Task.Delay(500);
    mockService.Verify(mock => mock.Process());
}
```